# GPU with Theano giving poor result compared to CPU with theano

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, theano

I am doing this tutorial:
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html#exercise

and the solution to the tutorial is given here:
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/_downloads/using_gpu_solution_1.py

But my issue is when I run the code

with GPU:

```
THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu time python using_gpu_solution_1.py
```

I got the following output:

```
Using gpu device 0: Tesla C2050 / C2070
Used the gpu
13.37user 3.69system 0:16.49elapsed 103%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 617376maxresident)k
0inputs+16outputs (0major+75442minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

and with CPU:

```
THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=cpu time python using_gpu_solution_1.py
```

I got the following output:

```
Used the cpu
6.85user 14.50system 0:04.43elapsed 481%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 241120maxresident)k
0inputs+16outputs (0major+43904minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

In [the solution](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/_downloads/using_gpu_solution_1.py) they have mentioned the speed up of almost double with GPU.
But I am getting more elapsed time with GPU than CPU.

Is it that the code ran on multiple core on CPU and it got improvements over GPU?

Can anyone tell me what I am getting wrong?
Only thing I can see is improve in system time using the GPU.
Is this what they mean by speed up? as the overall elapsed time is still more with GPU.

Answer (score 3):

There is one problems (1) and consideration about this(2-3):

1) You don't time correctly. The way you time, you include the theano compilation time. Theano compilation is not made to be included in the profile. You should only time the time spent inside Theano function. For this, modify the script of use the Theano profiler as in the profile.

2) This is a toy example. It do pure Stochastic Gradient Descent(SGD). To get good speed up from the GPU, we need to use minibatch with SGD. If we don't the GPU don't have enough data to parallellize the computation.

3) As this is a toy example with only a small model, the speed up will vary highly depending of the CPU and GPU used. It is probably that you did your timming on a better CPU then the original, or that you did it with a parallel BLAS.